# SQL - how to keep track of "simple relations"

Tags: sql, relation, table-structure

I hope somebody can edit my title to better describe what I mean, because I don't know exactly what this would be called. However, consider this setup: I want to create a notification system, where a message is displayed to a user until he clicks "dismiss". I then need to "remember" that this user has dismissed the notification so I don't show it to him again. Here is my current solution

- `users` table has a `uid` primary key and user info
- `notifications` table has a `nid` primary key and notification text
- `notifications_seen` table with two columns, `uid` and `nid`

When somebody clicks dismiss on a notification, I store their `uid` and the notification's `nid` in `notifications_seen`. This seems to work fine, but phpMyAdmin has giant red messages telling me that `notifications_seen` does not have an index. However, neither column is unique. Should I really have an extra utterly useless column in `notifications_seen` and call that a primary key? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why do i even want an index though?

Comment: The same reason you would want a card catalogue when you go to a library without computers.  Would you rather go look at all of the books, or just look at the cards with some information about all of the books that tell you where the books are when you find the specific ones you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than one column to create your primary key.  In this case, you should set nid AND uid as your primary key in your notifications_seen table.  The idea here is that even though neither nid or uid will be unique within your notifications_seen table; the nid/uid PAIR is unique.  You should add a primary key constraint to these two columns.  This is usually what you would like to do for this kind of situation.

There are times where you might actually want to create an auto-increment row to simplify the primary key.  For example, when your best candidate key consists of a lot of columns (I'm pulling this out of the air; but lets say 4 or more columns) or you have columns which contain strings; which would be slower to match when doing lookups.  But for this situation, just adding the primary key constraint to the two columns should be more than fine.

Primary keys are indexed BY default; which is why you should just add the primary key constraint to the two columns.  This will also preserve the integrity of your data by making sure you don't accidentally insert rows with the same uid/nid pair.

You should also add a foreign key constraint on the uid to the id in the users table, and a foreign key constraint to the nid on the id in the notifications table.  Adding the foreign key constraints will ensure you don't insert uids or nids which don't actually exist into your notifications_seen table.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an index on `notifications_seen` that contains *both* columns! Or create a separate column just for a primary key, or do both - having an index on `uid` and `nid` *might* speed up queries (but don't worry too much about that until you start to notice major performance problems - just remember it for the future). Having a primary key for these n:n relations isn't a terrible thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to create a compound primary key (consisting of both `uid` and `nid`).